# malloc is doing strange things with memory addresses

Tags: c, malloc

I am doing a bucket sort, sorting pointers to nodes into a linked list with a dummy header. The user inputs the values for the nodes, and then they are immediately dropped into their appropriate bucket. My problem arises when I am attempting to allocate the memory for the second node (not including the dummy header) for the linked list.

This is the code used to drop the nodes into the bucket, var being the value that is being sorted, and current being the newly created node to be sorted:

```
void bucketSort(int var, nodeptr current)
    if(!bucket[var])
    {
    buckets[var] = (nodeptr) malloc(sizeof(nodeptr));
    buckets[var]->next = current;
    bucketrear[var] = current;
    }
    else
    {
    bucketrear[var]->next = current;
    bucketrear[var] = current;
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version (less values) of the code used to create the new node:

```
void addNode(int value)
{
    nodeptr newNode;

    newNode= (nodeptr) malloc(sizeof(nodeptr));

    newNode->value = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;


    bucketDrop(value, newNode);
}
```

With Trace Statements, I discovered that before the Malloc of the second Node (with same value as the first), the Address of the bucket[value]->next was a normal address, but afterwards the address was 17. This value of 17 came up in every single test that I did.

Any help or ideas would be great. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: `sizeof nodeptr`? Don't you mean `sizeof node` or `sizeof *newNode`?

Comment: Can you paste your sctruc as well?

Comment: If you have memory being overwritten, then first check that you don't use pointers to local variables that you save. I also recommend tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Besides the bug already identified by Zeta, in C (different from C++) you shouldn't cast the return of `malloc`, this can hide subtle bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is one of solution.

```
buckets[var] = (nodeptr) malloc(sizeof(*buckets[var]));

newNode= (nodeptr) malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
```

Comment: Thank you, that did fix it.
I was using the malloc that had been provided in lectures, and my tutor assured me it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the struct for your node and the pointer pointing to it and thus overwriting the memory location.

Since you're casting the malloc result to a `nodeptr` type it means that this is a pointer (since malloc() returns a pointer) which also means your're allocating memory the size of a pointer.

So given that you named your struct `nodestruct`, to allocate enough memory you'd write

```
newNode = (nodeptr) malloc(sizeof(struct nodestruct));
```

Comment: Please, don't cast the return value of malloc() in C. And I think that using sizeof *newNode would be less error-prone that sizeof(struct nodestruct), but it can be argued I guess.

Comment: @RemiGacogne why wouldn't you cast the return value of malloc? If you don't want to use just `void*` in your code, you'll have to cast at some point anyway?!

Comment: Since ANSI C, a void pointer can be assigned to any pointer type safely, without the need of casting. So it's not needed anymore and as each cast can prevent the compiler to warn you about an error later, it should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

The following should resolve your issue:

newNode= (nodeptr) malloc(sizeof(*nodeptr));

The reason is nodeptr looks to be a pointer to struct, and hence you should allocate memory for the struct instead of a pointer.

From, next time please paste your struct definitions also.